# Stop a SourceDataLine from user input

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I want to make a music player in Java using SourceDataLine. I have method to start the sound but I need methods such as stop, pause, etc. The question is, how to stop already played sound from user input? I am guessing my class should be a thread but I am not exactly sure how.

```
public class MusicPlayer {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128_000;
    private File songFile;
    private AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    public void play(Song song){
        try {
            songFile = song.getSongFile();
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songFile);
            audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();

            byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1) {
                sourceDataLine.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.stop();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.out.println("Line is unavailable");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            System.out.println("Audio file is not supported");
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Song song = new Song();
        MusicPlayer player = new MusicPlayer();
        player.play(song);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(sc.next().equals("stop")) {
            player.stop(); // Something like this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add an instance variable and place it in the argument of the `while` command.

```
private volatile boolean running;
// add public setter/getter
```

and, have the `while` run in its own thread. Then, for the argument for the while:

```
while (running && ((bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) != -1))
```

The main idea is to make the `running` variable loosely coupled, reachable via the public setter, and to have the playback code continually consulting that variable. I'm not entirely sure, but I think the `volatile` setting on the boolean ensures the change in value occurs immediately even across multiple threads.